# Is this really a picture of John Young?

Tags: space-shuttle, astronauts

[This article](https://www.airspacemag.com/daily-planet/space-specs-147121745/) from the Smithsonian *Air and Space* magazine is about eyeglasses for astronauts.  The following quote about [legendary astronaut John Young](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43147/26446) is immediately followed by a picture:

> Even Apollo veteran John Young took his reading glasses along on STS-1.
>
> [image: picture from Air and Space]

The picure file is named "John-Young-glasses-400.jpg", but it doesn't look at all like other pictures of Young.  (Maybe it's a picture of whatever guy ran the Shuttle simulator.)  **Is this really a photo of John Young?**

For comparison, here is Young's official Apollo portrait:

[image: Apollo John Young]

Comment: obliquely related: answers to [Can astronauts wear eyeglasses inside their helmets during launches and landings?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21479)

Comment: Downvoted for lack of prior research. A search for John Young on the NASA image page turns up the picture. https://images.nasa.gov/details-S81-30419

Comment: @OrganicMarble: No, I certainly did perform a search for pictures of Young.  So any claim of "lack of research" is simply not true.  But your search was more successful.  It looks like you could post an answer, so why not please do that?

Comment: There are some great photos from that trip. What a ride! https://images.nasa.gov/details-S81-30422

Comment: Another picture showing only the right half of the face is needed for comparison.

Comment: That's John...looks like he's got a good case of "launch face" going on...

Comment: One point of similarity between the two photos in the question are the eyebrows. A second point could possibly be the nose.

Comment: Looks just like him to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's John...looks like he's got a good case of "launch face" going on...

Sorry, I cannot back up my answer with any specific citations (beyond what Organic Marble offered in a comment to the original post)...